# Deploy workflow quickly

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, workflow

I have to replace out of the box approval workflow on many sites ( Office 365 ) as they will not be available anymore in November. I know how to create a replacement workflow with SharePoint 2013 workflow and SharePoint designer. I would like to know if there is a quick way to deploy workflow on multiple sites and specify parameters like the list on which the workflow is running by the script to avoid going on each site to create workflows.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

You could refer [this article](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/understanding-how-to-package-and-deploy-workflow-in-sharepoint) to learn how to package and deploy workflow in SharePoint.

Comment: I tried to package workflow, it works fine except with start a task process action. I have set a custom task content type in outcome options which inherit from "Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)" but when I import the workflow and activate it as a solution. This Custom content type is not preserved and it put "Workflow Task (SharePoint 2013)" by default. I have to edit the workflow in SharePoint designer and put the correct content type. How to preserve this information to avoid workflows to be in errors and to edit them manually ?